# Multiple TinyMCE instances with Symfony 1.4

Tags: tinymce, symfony-1.4

I'm trying to set several forms in one page. Each has textarea with TinyMCE editor (from isicsWidgetFormTinyMCEPlugin). Unfortunately only the first textarea is decorated with the editor. All the remaining textareas are "bare".

How to set isicsWidgetFormTinyMCEPlugin to match all my inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you need to give each of your textareas a different id!
Tinymce uses the original textarea id to identify an editor. If more than one id is given to several textareas/html elments, only the first one gets initialized.

Comment: I managed to find it myself, just didn't put info here (busy).

I also encountered another problem, I'll describe it below.

Comment: that could be of help to others too